# Xlwings: date argument conversion

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

In an Excel cell I call function fff(DATE(2001,1,1)). To receive the date argument, I use (xlwings 0.10.0) the following code:

```
@xw.func
@xw.arg('req_date', dates=datetime.date) # I also tried datetime.datetime
def fff(req_date):
    print req_date
```

which prints just a number, not datetime object. I solved the problem by calling

```
req_date = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
           + datetime.timedelta(days=req_date)
```

but I wonder what did I do wrong with the xlwings way?!

Answer (score 2):

xlwings only performs the automatic transformation into a `datetime` object if the cell in Excel is formatted as a Date. That is, if you put `=DATE(2001,1,1)` into one cell and then in a different cell write `=fff('A1')`, it will work as you expect (assuming that the date formula is in A1).

Comment: OK, it does work (of course). But I am afraid it is a little bit misleading. I thought that by using @arg I do specify the type of argument. Nevermind, this is a minor feature.

Comment: Currently, the date converter only works on date formatted cells. I get your point thought - might be a future enhancement.